# Search for an address using a free text field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that looks like this i.e. address is a free text field (I did not design it):

```
5 records from the Address Table:
1 The street
2 Pine Street,Lincoln,Lincolnshire
77 Drove Way,Grantham
Drove Way Lincoln
Some house on Ambleside
```

I have an application that has an address field that is free text (again I did not design it).  I want a user to start typing an address into the address field and then a list of Possibles to appear (hopefully just one).  I have thought of a few ways to approach this:

```
1) Use a LIKE statement e.g. select * FROM dbaddress where address like '%1 The Street%'.  This seems like a bad idea.
2) Free text search.  I have not used this before.
```

Which is the "better option" for my requirements.  Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have had something like this before and free text was a better a option in my case. If you can use `LIKE 'abc%'` which you use an index is also a better option.

For a field like address it's better to search with begin with.

At the end based on your needs, If I were you I would execute both queries and compare them in execution plan.